# Excel Macro: Selecting a specific Row based on column date

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am writing my first macro and have a question on how I can select a specific Row based on a value in a specific column. here is my code so far:

```
Sub Pipeline()

'Module 3
'Iterating through the Funding Date Column and looking for clients going live within 30 days
'Selecting the rows for each client in that target range
'TODO: Export information into an email template in Outlook
'TODO: Send email to distribution list


Dim fundingDate As range
Set fundingDate = range("M4:M500")

Dim todaysDate As Date
todaysDate = Date

For Each cell In fundingDate
  If cell < todaysDate + 30 Then
   'Need to select the entire row
  Else
  cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Since you say this is your first macro , here's a hint: always use `Option Explicit` (put this as the first line in your module).  This will force you to declare _all_ your variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace `'Need to select the entire row` with

`cell.entirerow.select`

**UPDATE** 
Here is a much more efficient way to get what you need without all the looping.

In your code Replace from `For Each cell ...` to `Next` with this:

```
With fundingDate    
    .AutoFilter 1, "<" & todaysDate + 30        
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select 
    'here are your clients going live in next 30 days    
    .AutoFilterMode = False    
End With
```

You may need to provide some error checking in case you don't have clients going live within 30 days (`SpecialCells` method will fail on this) and also, if M4 is not your column header, you may want to adjust how the range picks up the visible cells.

Comment: Hi Scott, how does the .AutoFilter work? I thought the dot notation had to be used to call a method on an object? Also, when I copy and paste the above code I am recieving an error because of the .AutoFilterMode = False that says "Runtime error 438, Object doesnt support this propety or method"

Comment: Also, how would I specify that I want the sheet to only display one row(for rows that are grouped)? Thanks!

Comment: @BC00 -> I am running out the door now, but to help with your questions: `How does the .AutoFilter work?` - please see the Help in Excel for this. Or use the Filter method on any given range, manually, to see how it works. `. notation` -> this calling a method on an object. You are calling the `AutoFilter` Method on the `fundingDate` range object, it's just using a `With` statement to make the code easier to read and more efficient. `RunTime Error` -> make sure you have a valid range selected that can filter by date. Have fun out there!